# Why update the D ascending in Generative Adversarial networks?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

I found GANs very very powerfull and start reading the papres around it. 
This is the algoritm used in [The original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661) to describe the steps of updating Descriminator and Generative parts of the network.

I underestand that the `log(1-D(G(z)))` must be minimized but why should we maximise the `log(D(xi))+log(1-D(G(z)))`? it refers to the discriminator part so it can compare the `P(g)` to `P(data)`. so it's a kind of Error rate. why are we maximizing it!?

[image: Minibatch stochastic gradient descent training of generative adversarial nets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't update the discriminator, then the generator would never get any better.

"Adversarial" is the key. If you started with some fixed discriminator and optimized the generator to beat that, then your generator will get good enough to trick that particular adversary. But that doesn't mean it's any good, unless you picked a very good discriminator to start with. That's hard; it's much easier to pick a class of possible adversaries, and then try to come up with a model that can beat *all* discriminators of that form. That's what the optimization attempts to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your answer. ok so we need to update Discriminator to feet the real data better and better so it can compare real data and generated data. but why Maximizing the Term `log(D(xi))+log(1-D(G(z)))`? shouldn't we minimize it? isn't it a form of discriminating error?

Comment: That's the negative of the [binary cross-entropy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy), which is a measure of classification quality; if $D$ is 1 on the $X$ samples and 0 on the $G$ samplrs then its value is 0. If it's 1/2 on everything then the value is $-2\log 2$. So maximizing it gives a better classifier, ie a stronger discriminator.

Comment: Wow. thanks. now I got it. thanks a lot, Dougal. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your worry is right. Here is a terminology confusion.

Consider this objective function:
$$\log D ( x^{(i)}) + \log ( 1−D ( G ( z^{(i)} )))$$

The first term requires $D$ to correctly recognise real data. The closer $D(x)$ is to 1 (True), the closer the term $\log D ( x^{(i)})$ is to 0. And this term is always negative or 0. Similarly, for the second term $\log ( 1−D ( G ( z^{(i)} )))$, situation is the same. They all requires the objective function as closer to zero as possible, which in numeral is ascending the objective function to zero.

The description here is misleading, as we usually refer 'stochastic gradient descending (SGD)' as a method for weight updating but not to describe the actual value of objective functions.

The sentences

> 'Update the discriminator by **ascending** its stochastic gradient'
> 'Update the generator by **descending** its stochastic gradient'

should be replaced with

> 'Update the discriminator with an optimiser for **ascending the objective
> function's value**'
> 'Update the generator with an optimiser for **descending the objective
> function's value**'

if we must use 'ascending' and 'descending' here.